# How to do a Mercurial merge in case multiple branches are active?

Tags: merge, mercurial, branch, branching-and-merging

I have following structure of branches in my Mercurial repository

```
               ----------B-------
              /
             /
-----default----------------------------
             \    \            /
              \    \          /
               --------A------
                     \
                      \
                       ------C------
```

I would like to do a merge of the `default` branch with the `B` branch (where the `B` branch is my "working" branch). My idea how to do that was to "switch" onto the default `branch` at first.
So I intended to do following steps

1. `hg update default` (for switching onto the `default` branch)
2. `hg merge B` (for "pulling" the changes on the `B` branch onto the `default` branch)
3. resolving the conflicts
4. `hg commit` (for making the merge persistent)

Please can anybody tell me whether the steps which I am going to use can work also in my situation i.e. in case I have default branch and two other active (open) branches from which only one of them is intended to be merged with the default?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of your proposed workflow would be this:

```
               ----------B------- - - 
              /                       \
             /                         \
-----default----------------------------(*)
             \    \            /
              \    \          /
               --------A------
                     \
                      \
                       ------C------
```

Where the (*) marks the current working directory immediately afterwards.

The fact that there is a branch `C` shouldn't cause any concern. There could be any # of other branches like `C` and until you merge with them individually, they would have no effect on your merge of `B` into `default`.

Assuming that `A` and `B` are no longer needed, you can close them. This just serves as a marker / reminder that work on them is finished but it doesn't have much other practical effect. For instance, you could resume work on a closed branch later and even re-merge it back to `default` if needed. (On the other hand you could also branch off from `default` again and do that work there.)